# Kamailio startup errors

Tags: kamailio

I've just installed a new Ubuntu 16.10 server distro and started the install of Kamailio. After fixing some db create errors (MEDIUMTEXT does not support a default value in MySQL 5.7) I tried to start the service. The following errors are reported from journalctl:

```
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 292, column 30: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <acc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 293, column 37: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <acc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 295, column 73: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <acc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 296, column 45: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <usrloc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 310, column 75: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <usrloc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 311, column 32: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <usrloc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 312, column 35: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <auth_db> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 318, column 76: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <auth_db> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 319, column 41: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <auth_db> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 320, column 50: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <auth_db> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 321, column 43: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <auth_db> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 322, column 36: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <rtpproxy> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 363, column 77: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <nathelper> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 366, column 45: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <nathelper> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 367, column 43: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <nathelper> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 368, column 41: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <nathelper> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 369, column 64: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <nathelper|registrar> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 372, column 65: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <usrloc> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 373, column 34: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <tls> found
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 379, column 50: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command is_method (params 1)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 418, column 24: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command t_check_trans (params 0)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 420, column 21: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command t_relay (params 0)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 421, column 12: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command t_check_trans (params 0)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 425, column 16: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command remove_hf (params 1)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 432, column 19: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command is_method (params 1)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 433, column 34: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command record_route (params 0)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 434, column 16: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3228]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command is_method (params 1)
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 437, column 24: unknown command, missing loadmodule?
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [pvapi.c:828]: pv_parse_spec2(): error searching pvar "rU"
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [pvapi.c:1031]: pv_parse_spec2(): wrong char [U/85] in [$rU] at [2 (0)]
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3365]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 453, column 6-8: Can't get from cache: $rU
kamailio[5177]: INFO: <core> [sctp_core.c:53]: sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized
polkitd(authority=local)[1602]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5167:439835 (system bus name :1.32, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent,
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always happens this way... I'll search and search for an answer, finally give up and post a question, then find an answer.

In this case, the answer is to modify the mpath= variable in the kamailio.cfg file to point to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the parameters for modules that you haven't loaded into the configure and/or haven't compiled.

Example:

```
kamailio[5177]: : <core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 292, column 30: Can't set module parameter
kamailio[5177]: ERROR: <core> [modparam.c:150]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <acc> found
```

Do you have a line in your config that looks like the following?  If you do, it is that you don't have the modules compiled.

```
loadmodule "acc"
```

If you installed from source,  look at the documentation where it mentions modifying the modules.lst file and you need to include the modules that you intend to use before you "make all".

If you installed from apt. Do a "apt-cache search kamailio" to see the list of packages.  Then install the missing packages.

Example (this package contains the acc module):

```
apt install kamailio-berkeley-modules
```

You can use the Ubuntu Package Search (https://packages.ubuntu.com/) to find which packages contain the modules that you are missing as well.